# Trying to populate props with async promise inside of ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So inside of my uncontrolled PossibleMatches component, I know from the way React works, the initial rendering phase will occur with empty prop values (if those prop values rely on external application state (mapStateToProps)) regardless of whether or not I have a componentDidMount lifecycle method or constructor setup. In response to this, I've setup a promise inside of the componentDidMount so that when I dispatch prop functions [defaultPieces, arrangePieces], I can have the UI render an ActivityIndicator to indicate something is currently fetching. The problem is, I cannot seem to get the mapStateToProps function to understand the state when I call mapStateToProps from within the success phase of the promise. Here it is:

```
class PossibleMatches extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

componentDidMount(props){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let state;
        let {defaultPieces, arrangePieces, isFetching} = this.props;
        let makeClothesAppear = function(){
            defaultPieces();
            arrangePieces();
            isFetching = true;
        }

        resolve(makeClothesAppear());
    }).then(function(state){
        mapStateToProps(state);
        this.props.isFetched = true
        this.props.isFetching = false;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('FetchClothesError: ', error);
    })
}
}
```

**How the UI would make a decision on what to display:**

```
renderDecision(){

        const {UpperComponents, LowerComponents} = this.props;
        const {currentUpperComponent, currentLowerComponent} = this.state.currentComponent.whichPiece;
        const {LowerComponentEnabled, UpperComponentEnabled} = this.state;

        if (this.props.isFetching){
             return (<div className='activityLoader'>
                        <ActivityIndicator number={3} duration={200} activeColor="#fff" borderWidth={2} borderColor="50%" diameter={20}/>
                     </div>);
        } else if (this.props.isFetched){
                return (<div className = "PossibleMatches_Container">
                        <i className = 'captureOutfit' onClick = {this.snapshotMatch}></i> 
                            {UpperComponents.map((component) => {                               
                                    return (<UpperComponent key={component.createdAt} id={component.id} 
                                               switchComponent={this.switchFocus} 
                                               setCurrentPiece = {this.setNewPiece} 
                                               evaluatePiece={this.isOppositeComponentSuggested}
                                               image={component.image}
                                               toggleToPiece = {(LowerComponentEnabled) => {if (LowerComponentEnabled === false){this.setState({LowerComponentEnabled: true})}else{return;} this.setState({currentLowerComponent: this.props.suggestedBottoms[0]})}} 
                                               isLowerComponentEnabled={LowerComponentEnabled}
                                               ref={this.residingUpperComponent}
                                               className = {this.state.currentComponent.whichPiece.whichType === 'match' ? 'PossibleMatches_Container' : this.state.currentComponent.whichPiece.whichType === 'bottom' ? 'standalonePiece' : 'standalonePiece'}/>)
                                    })
                            }
                            {LowerComponents.map((component) => {
                                    return  (<LowerComponent key={component.createdAt} id={component.id} 
                                               setCurrentPiece = {this.setNewPiece} 
                                               evaluatePiece={this.isOppositeComponentSuggested}
                                               image={component.image}
                                               toggleToPiece={(UpperComponentEnabled) => {if (UpperComponentEnabled === false){this.setState({UpperComponentEnabled: true})}else{return;} this.setState({currentUpperComponent: this.props.suggestedTops[0]})}}                
                                               switchComponent={this.switchFocus}
                                               isUpperComponentEnabled={UpperComponentEnabled}
                                               ref={this.residingLowerComponent}
                                               className = {this.state.currentComponent.whichPiece.whichType === 'match' ? 'PossibleMatches_Container' : this.state.currentComponent.whichPiece.whichType === 'bottom' ? 'standalonePiece' : 'standalonePiece'}/>)                                                  
                                    })
                            }
                        </div>)
        }
    }

    render(){


        return(  

                <div className = 'GorClothingContainer'>
                    {/*<Wardrobe upperComponent={this.state.currentComponent.whichPiece.currentUpperComponent} lowerComponent={this.state.currentComponent.whichPiece.currentLowerComponent} enableCapture={(snapshot) => this.snapshotMatch = snapshot} />*/}
                      {this.renderDecision()}
               </div>
            );
    }
```

**My PossibleMatches Reducer**

```
import {INITIAL_PIECES, GET_ANCILLARY_PIECES, ORGANIZE_PIECES, SET_CONTEMPLATED_PIECE} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
     UpperComponents: [],
     LowerComponents: [],
     contemplated_piece: null,
     extraTops: [],
     extraBottoms: [],
     standaloneTops: [],
     standaloneBottoms: [],
     suggestedTops: [],
     suggestedBottoms: []
}

export default function(state = initialState, action){

    switch(action.type){
        case INITIAL_PIECES:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {contemplated_piece: action.payload.contemplated_piece},
                                            {extraTops: action.payload.extra_tops},
                                            {extraBottoms: action.payload.extra_bottoms},
                                            {standaloneTops: action.payload.standalone_tops},
                                            {standaloneBottoms: action.payload.standalone_bottoms},
                                            {suggestedTops: action.payload.suggested_tops},
                                            {suggestedBottoms: action.payload.suggested_bottoms})
        case GET_ANCILLARY_PIECES:
           return Object.assign({}, state, {extraTops: action.payload.extra_tops},
                                           {extraBottoms: action.payload.extra_bottoms},
                                           {standaloneTops: action.payload.standalone_tops},
                                           {standaloneBottoms: action.payload.standalone_bottoms},
                                           {suggestedTops: action.payload.suggested_tops},
                                           {suggestedBottoms: action.payload.suggested_bottoms})
        case ORGANIZE_PIECES:
               return Object.assign({}, state, {UpperComponents: action.payload.UpperComponents},
                                               {LowerComponents: action.payload.LowerComponents})           
        case SET_CONTEMPLATED_PIECE:
           return Object.assign({}, state, {contemplated_piece: action.payload.contemplated_piece})
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**My combineReducers segment**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

const allReducers = combineReducers({
 Playlist: PlaylistReducer,
 eventOptions: eventTicketReducer,
 possibleMatches: PossibleMatchesReducer,
 Intro: combineForms({
        basicUserInfo: BasicUserInfoState,
        GenderInfo: GenderInfoState,
        ContactInfo: ContactInfoState
       }, 'Intro'),
 routing: routerReducer,
 form: formReducer
});
```

**Prop Values:**

```
PossibleMatches.defaultProps = {
    isFetching: true,
    isFetched: false
}
```

**My mapStateToProps function**

```
function mapStateToProps(state){

            return {UpperComponents: state.possibleMatches.UpperComponents,
                    LowerComponents: state.possibleMatches.LowerComponents,
                    contemplatedPiece: state.possibleMatches.contemplated_piece,
                    extraTops: state.possibleMatches.extraTops,
                    extraBottoms: state.possibleMatches.extraBottoms,
                    standaloneTops: state.possibleMatches.standaloneTops,
                    standaloneBottoms: state.possibleMatches.standaloneBottoms,
                    suggestedTops: state.possibleMatches.suggestedTops,
                    suggestedBottoms: state.possibleMatches.suggestedBottoms}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
      return {
        defaultPieces: () => {
          dispatch(defaultPieces())
        },
        arrangePieces: () => {
            dispatch(arrangePieces())
        },
        getCorrespondingPieces: () => {
            dispatch(getCorrespondingPieces())
        },
        setEvaluatedPiece: () => {
            dispatch(setEvaluatedPiece())
        }
      }
    }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PossibleMatches)
```

My Question is: What exactly is wrong with the way that I've implemented the promise. With the reducers and the redux actions setup correctly(I know because I've logged the fetched items to the console from the redux actions file), how can I properly populate the prop values in mapStateToProps. Currently the error is:

[image]

Im using React 16.4.0

Comment: The problem is with the the state path provided in mapStateToProps. state.possiblematches is undefined. If you provide me your redux combineReducers() object, I could give you a better answer.

Comment: I'll edit my question right now to include that.

Comment: Also why do you call mapStateToProps in the componentDidMount? That seems a bit wrong.

Comment: Thats why I posted this. How can I populate the props inside of mapStateToProps to ensure that those props can be used inside of the component?

Comment: Redux is a global store. You throw actions to update the store. If you want to access the state of the store you use connect HoC (Higher order component, consider it as a function for now). What the connect function does is that it takes two arguments, the first one being the mapStateToProps, which maps redux states (denoted by the path you give in the rhs e.g. state.possibleMatches.UpperComponents) to props that would then be injected in your component.

Comment: I understand that. I've implemented all of that above but how am I suppose to correctly populate the keys inside of mapStateToProps after the component has gone through its initial rendering cycle. The initial rendering cycle only knows about the initialState specified in the possible Matches reducer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple redux use case would seem as follows

possibleMatches.jsx (Component file)

```
class PossibleMatches extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isFetching: false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({isFetching: true})
    fetchingSomethingFromServer()
    .then(resp => {
      this.setState({isFetching: false})
      this.props.UpdateRedux(resp)
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { isFetching } = this.state;
    const { data } = this.props;
    return (
      isFetching ? <div>loading...</div> : <div>{data}</div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({ data: state.possibleMatches.data }), {UpdateRedux})
```

actions.js (action creator file)
Use this action to update any data into redux

```
export const UpdateRedux = (data) => {type: 'UPDATE_REDUX', payload: data}
```

reducers.js
This is the file that holds the redux state

```
const defaultState = {
 data: null
}

export default (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_REDUX':
      return {data: action.payload};
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

In your combine reducers import this reducer and assign it as follows

```
import possibleMatches from 'reducers.js';

combineReducers({ possibleMatches });
```

Comment: This is cool but essentially it does the same thing I was doing above. That fetchSomething method you are calling performs functionality that {defaultPieces and arrangePieces} is performing. It also updates the reducer with the new values so there is no need for the redux function updateRedux above. I know the values are properly fetched w/ {arrangePieces, defaultPieces} because i have console.log statements inside of the functions defined.

Comment: Your logic is totally wrong in the componentDidMount. I don't see any action creators.

Comment: Please specify. I have defaultPieces() and arrangePieces() inside of makeClothesAppear function. That makeClothesAppear is put inside of the resolve method. Inside of mapDispatchToProps, I have those two functions.